# Using CIRD notation

Tags: python, networking, range, bandwidth, notation

I want to specify this range in scapy to send ARP request to, the range is from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.254
Is this the correct way to present it
192.168.0.1/24
If not how could I represented?
Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but it is not the correct way to represent class "C" network. Your mask is /24 and you have set bits in the last octet - 1 at the end.

Correct notation will be 192.168.0.0/24.

You can use ipcalc utility (https://iptools.onssh.com/ipcalc) to understand this structure.